# (Symfony 4) Creating a select dropdown from multiselect entity form field

Tags: forms, symfony, select

I have a Symfony form type class like the following:

```
class FeedFilterType extends AbstractType

{
 /**
 * @var UserProvider
 */
protected $userProvider;

/**
 * @var UserRepository $userRepository
 */
protected $userRepository;

public function __construct(UserProvider $userProvider, UserRepository $userRepository)
{
    $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
    $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('creators', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => User::class,
            'choices'  => $this->userRepository->getCreatorsSubscribedToByUser($this->userProvider->getCurrentUser()),
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'required' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true
        ])
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array());
}
```

}

It works properly in that it brings back the array of users, but when I add it to my twig, like:

```
{{ form_widget(feedFilterForm.creators) }}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I could easilly manually build a select drop-down from the resulting array of entities, but does Symfony have a built-in select DOM html type, resulting from the array of entities brought back from a form?

Comment: According to the docs : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#select-tag-checkboxes-or-radio-buttons, try to set `expanded` to `false`

Comment: Hi Mathieu, that was it thank you.